# Move uploaded file and WordPress

Tags: wordpress, file-upload

I am trying to upload an image to a WordPress website using my custom code but it is not working. The directory is writable and there is no other error. The subdirectory 'contracts' was created manually.

```
$uploads = wp_get_upload_dir();
$fileTmpPath = $_FILES['upload_img']['tmp_name'];
$fileName = $_FILES['upload_img']['name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['upload_img']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES[$filename]['type'];
$fileNameCmps = explode(".", $fileName);
$fileExtension = strtolower(end($fileNameCmps));
$newFileName = md5(time() . $fileName) . '.' . $fileExtension;
$allowedfileExtensions = array('jpg', 'gif', 'png');
if (in_array($fileExtension, $allowedfileExtensions)) {
    $dest_path = $uploads['basedir'].'/contracts/'. $newFileName;

    if ( !is_writeable( $upload_path ) ) {
        echo 'Unable to write to directory.';
    }
    if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpPath, $dest_path)){
        echo $uploads['baseurl'].'/contracts/'.$newFileName;    
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also include your form's code in your question so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi @cabrerahector, I am using contact form 7,  and using this hook :
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'mycustom_function' ); 
everything on form side is correct, if i print $_FILES, it correctly print it. It just not upload file to directory.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small typo in the code, not sure if this would stop execution but non the less try with this code

```
$uploads = wp_get_upload_dir();
$fileTmpPath = $_FILES['upload_img']['tmp_name'];
$fileName = $_FILES['upload_img']['name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['upload_img']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['upload_img']['type'];
$fileNameCmps = explode(".", $fileName);
$fileExtension = strtolower(end($fileNameCmps));
$newFileName = md5(time() . $fileName) . '.' . $fileExtension;
$allowedfileExtensions = array('jpg', 'gif', 'png');
if (in_array($fileExtension, $allowedfileExtensions)) {
    $dest_path = $uploads['basedir'].'/contracts/'. $newFileName;

   if ( !is_writeable( $upload_path ) ) {
      echo 'Unable to write to directory.';
   }
   if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpPath, $dest_path)){
     echo $uploads['baseurl'].'/contracts/'.$newFileName;   
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the final } ? No that is not the issue.

Comment: no, there was a error in this `$fileType = $_FILES[$filename]['type'];` i changed it to `$fileType = $_FILES['upload_img']['type'];`

Comment: That is not the issue.

Comment: ok, can you include your form HTML or the form as its in CF7 in your question.